# Using amsmath package in elsarticle preprint

Tags: amsmath, fractions, elsarticle

I am trying to add a fraction to my manuscript. I am using the elsarticle preprint template. Below you can find the important parts of the preamble. When I put \usepackage{amsmath} directly below \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle} I get a 'Package natbib Warning:' for all my citations and the document doesn't load.

Anyone understand what is happening and how I can fix this? (hope I'm giving enough information)

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\journal{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author[inst1]{...}
\affiliation[inst1]{organization={...}}
\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\input{Sections/...}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} 
\bibliography{cas-refs}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Link to the elsarticle-harv.bst bibliography style I'm using: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst

I'm using the 11/2020 version of the elsarticle.cls: https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle

Comment: The class has a new version on the same CTAN page (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle). The README explains how to get the `.cls` file from the `.dtx` and `.ins` files. This version is from 2020, so much newer than the 2008 version from your link. Try if it works with the new version (it probably does). Note that there are some differences, for example `\affiliation` is now `\address`.

Comment: Please tell us more about the contents of the natbib warning. Separately, what happens if you add `authoryear` to the list of options of the `\documentclass` diective?

Comment: @Marijn I see I accidentally sent the wrong link, I'm using the 2007-2020 version from the link you sent. It still has `\affiliation` but now ` \address` can be added to the document in addition to this. 

So this is the version I'm using:

`\def\RCSfile{elsarticle}% 
\def\RCSversion{3.3}% 
\def\RCSdate{2020/11/20}%`

Comment: @Mico Here is an example of a warning: "Package natbib Warning: Citation 'Ilyas2019' on page 2 undefined on input line 8."

Changing the` \documentclass` to `\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}` doesn't work unfortunately..

Comment: Did you run a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more) after adding the `authoryear` document class option? Is the entry with key `Ilyas2019` the only citation reference that couldn't be resolved?

Comment: @Mico I'm working in Overleaf and so I'm not sure if 'Recompile from scratch' is the same thing, but that is what I did. It is really strange, still whenever I put `\usepackage{amsmath}` below the document class it doesn't want to compile... The warning happens for all of my citations, not just the Ilyas one!

Comment: @jkool - Have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the great tip, the customer service at Overleaf was very helpful and I fixed the problem!